# Showing some uiview like UILocalNotification

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I nothing found on this subject, may be you help me.
**How showing some uiview at the specified time and day interval like method UILocalNotification repeatInterva?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see if it's a given day of the week and check the time using `NSCalendar`:

```
// Request the day, hour and minute components of the current date
NSUInteger dayHourMinuteComponents = NSWeekdayCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit;
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *nowDate = [NSDate date];
NSCalendarComponents *nowComponents = [calendar components:dayHourMinuteComponents fromDate:nowDate];
if (nowComponents.weekday == 2 && nowComponents.hour == 10 && nowComponents.minute == 0)
{
    // It's Monday at 10:00 - configure view here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need anything special. Just use a regular UIViewController, and configure its appearance differently depending on the current date. You can do it in the view controller's `viewDidLoad:` method.

Comment: I need repeat time interval like UIlocalNotification but inside app

Comment: How is this related to the original question?

Comment: i'm sorry, change question.